# How to conduct a lookup of an EJB from a servlet context?

Tags: servlets, ejb, apache-tomee

I have a POJO that was instantiated from a servlet. I need to make a lookup of an EJB within this POJO, either CDI or JNDI. My JEE container is TomEE 1.6.0.

My question is this: need the EJB have remote interface? Because if I instantiate it directly from the servlet by @EJB the remote interface does not need...

Just see this simple example which always throws NameNotFoundException.

```
@Stateless
public class MyEJB
{
    public String sayHello()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

The next servlet try yo lookup MyEJB:

```
@WebServlet("/myServlet")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID=1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException
    {
        try
        {
            Context ctx = new InitialContext();
            MyEJB ejb = (MyEJB) ctx.lookup("MyEJB");

            System.out.println(ejb.sayHello());            
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

The line: `MyEJB ejb = (MyEJB) ctx.lookup("MyEJB");` always throws NameNotFoundException. But if I use @EJB it work fine. But I need do the lookup in JNDI mode because finally I will instantiate this EJB within a POJO.

So, why fails this lookup ?

Comment: Can you just pass the EJB to the POJO from the servlet? I'd either pass it as a constructor argument or by using a setter. You could also just use it as a method argument. You should be able to inject it into your servlet.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with remote interfaces.

When you declare MyEJB in servlet using @EJB it works, because servlet is container-managed - your TomEE server instantiates servlet object. However declaration of MyEJB in MyPojo (also using @EJB) won't work, because MyPojo is **not** container-managed - it is created using new MyPojo(), not by TomEE server.

You could for example make MyPojo another EJB (using @Stateless) and inject it using @EJB to the servlet - not by creating new MyPojo().

Comment: ) I know that. But what I want to know is if the EJB need have remote interface so It can be lookuped from MyPojo. Is remote interface needed or not?

Comment: Not if the POJO is local.

Comment: @Tomasz Nowak  Please, take a look at my question again, 
I edited the code to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I can solve this problem by myself by instrospecting the JNDI tree with this simple class:

```
import javax.naming.Binding;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NameClassPair;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;

public class JndiInstrospector
{
    public static void print()
    {
        try
        { 
            Context ctx = new InitialContext();
            String n = ctx.getNameInNamespace();
            _print(n);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }

    private static void _print(String name) throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Name in manespace: "+name);
            Context ctx = new InitialContext();
            NamingEnumeration<Binding> list = ctx.listBindings(name);

            while( list.hasMoreElements() )
            {
                Binding b = list.nextElement();
                String s = b.getName();

                _print(name+"/"+s);
            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // ignore
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, the EJB That I was espected to lookup was found at:
"java:/openejb/local/FacadeBeanLocalBean", where FacadadeBean is the name of my EJB (stateless session bean).